# Redux store does not clear on refresh

Tags: reactjs, redux

We are using redux persist. I am wondering, how do I clear some part of the state on refresh ?

Comment: your question is not clear. could you please explain more? 
are you persisting store or not??

Comment: I am using redux persist

Comment: this may help you : https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist#blacklist--whitelist

Answer (score 2):

The point of redux-persist is pretty much that the store does not clear on refresh.

If you only want to persist parts of the store, either only persist some reducers, not your root reducer - or use the `whitelist` and `blacklist` features to define what exactly should be persisted.